# Data Service Reflection Provider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a existing model with classes that reads the model from a number of files from disk. I use this in a current ASP.NET MVC project and to read the correct files from disk the classes handling the read needs a *version* URL parameter and a Request.PhysicalApplicationPath parameter. This is easy when I'm in a ASP.NET MVC controller and have the Request object and the incoming parameters form the URL.

When I then however want to use a Data Service class to expose my model I first need to be able to send the same URL parameter and the Request object to the classes for reading the model. I don't get how I should be able to access the URL parameters and the Request object when I'm in my svc file or how I should be able to get these to the "context" object with the get property that I have to read my model?

Update:
I would like to have something like the below where "23456" would then be the version number that I can forward to my classes that reads the model from disk and the rest is queries I pass on to the DataService to do it's magic.

```
http://MySite/23456/MyService/Category(1)/Products?$top=2&$orderby=name
```

So basically - is it possible to both use MVC for routing and parameter control etc and then pass the rest of the query to DataService to get the full flexibility of asking URL based questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to provide some context-specific data that is available in your controller to an underlying service (a data service in this case).

Typically, the easier and most straightforward way to do that is to make it the responsibility of the controller to pull out context-specific data and forward it along to the service as standard method parameters.

Is there something about your current situation that prevents you from grabbing the Version and Url data in the controller and passing them down to the service tier?

Comment: But then I have to make the queries "static", for example get me top 100 or by category for example. Is there a way to combine the flexibility with DataService and the route/parameter handling of MVC?

Comment: It depends on the way you are handling your data layer, but if it suits your needs, your data tier could return an IQueryable<T>, which could further refine using Linq in the controller by adding the additional constraints like Version and Url which are coming out of the HttpContext or whatever..